# Problema ao passar array como parâmetro

Tags: c

Não estou conseguido passar os parâmetros dos array corretamente para a função `calculos`. O código compila corretamente, mas a função não recebe os valores que estou tentando passar. Como é um array do tipo struct, deve está ai o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct faculdade
{
  char disc[40];
  int mat;
  int rfreq;
  int arpro;
} facu;


void calculos(int quant[],int aprov[],int repr[],float *por_apr,float *por_re)
{ int i;



    int total=0;
    int total_apro=0;
    int total_re=0;

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
    total+=quant[i];
    total_apro+=aprov[i];
    total_re+=repr[i];}
    *por_apr=((float)total_apro/total)*100;
    *por_re=((float)total_re/total)*100;



}








int main(){
  facu d[100];
  int i,n=1;
  float p_ap,p_re;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
      printf("Digite a %d° disciplina:\n",i+1);
      scanf("\n%[^\n]", d[i].disc );
      printf("digite quantos alunos foram matriculados na disciplina %s:\n",d[i]);
      scanf("%d", &d[i].mat );
      printf("digite quantos alunos foram aprovados na disciplina %s:\n",d[i]);
      scanf("%d", &d[i].arpro );
      printf("digite quantos alunos foram reprovados na disciplina %s:\n",d[i]);
      scanf("%d", &d[i].rfreq );
    }for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("\nmatriculados %d\n",d[i].mat);
    printf("aprovados %d\n",d[i].arpro);}

    calculos(d->mat,d->arpro,d->rfreq,&p_ap,&p_re);







  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `d` é um *array* do tipo `facu`, definido pela *struct*; na função você espera um *array* de *int*, mas passa o valor de um atributo `mat` de `d`, que é um *array*? Que confuso isso. O que realmente queria fazer?

Comment: QUERO PASSAR OS VALORES ARMAZENADOS NOS ARRAY PARA A FUNÇAO

Comment: Então, por favor, edite a pergunta e seja mais claro quanto a sua necessidade. Explique com textos o que o código deveria fazer e o que ele está fazendo no momento. Se está dando alguma mensagem de erro, coloque também a mensagem. Aproveite e faça o [tour] para aprender como o site funciona e leia o guia de [ask]. Lembre-se de desligar o *caps lock*.

Comment: Dei uma editada, obrigado pelas dicas

Comment: Não há vetor de inteiro sendo passado. O código deve ter vários avisos de compilação, e rodar até o fim é uma coincidência

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara tipo, eu meio que não entendi direito o que você deseja com essa função, se puder me explicar eu tenho certeza que poderei melhorar a minha resposta para o seu melhor entendimento, mas indo direto a resposta.

Primeiro passe a sua `struct` direto nos parâmetros já que você está trabalhando com ela de qualquer forma, tipo assim `void calculos ( facu* dado, int tam, float* por_apr, float* por_re )`, é muito importante ressaltar que quando se passa um vetor por parâmetro **você tem que passar o tamanho dele**,  porque senão a função não saberá qual é, e isso pode resultar em erros, vetores podem ser passados em parâmetros de duas formas, seguindo o exemplo acima, como `facu* dado` ou `facu dado[]`, ambos são a mesma coisa só que em um o ponteiro está implícito.

É importante que já que você não sabe qual será o tamanho do vetor, pergunte ao usuário, assim aloque um vetor de tamanho correto, desta forma você tem um ganho na performance.

Para fazer uma alocação dinâmica basta ter a biblioteca `<stdlib.h>` incluída e de pois declare um ponteiro para o tipo que você quer alocar em seguida chame a função `malloc`, ex: `facu* d = (facu*)malloc(sizeof(facu) * tam);`, ela funciona da seguinte maneira, nos parâmetros da `malloc` você irá passar o tamanho do tipo de dado que esta usando (muito recomendado que use `sizeof`, já que o tamanho pode variar de arquitetura para arquitetura) e o tamanho que deseja que seu vetor tenha, é muito importante lembrar que você sempre deve fazer um casting para o tipo de ponteiro que você esta usando, por isso o `(facu*)`, e também sempre lembre-se de quando terminar de usar vetor liberar o espaço alocado na memória com o comando `free`, ex: `free(d);`.

Você também teve um pequeno erro no seu primeiro `scanf`, `scanf("\n%[^\n]", d[i].disc );`, eu não sei se foi proposital ou não, mas não faça isso apague este `\n`, e lembre-se sempre de deixar um espaço entre as aspas e o %.., porque assim evita erros de buffers, de qualquer formar a maneira que eu considero correta de se fazer esse `scanf` é, `scanf(" %[^\n]s", d[i].disc );`.

Sem mais delongas aqui está a resposta (eu acho).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct faculdade
{
  char disc[40];
  int mat;
  int rfreq;
  int arpro;
} facu;

void calculos ( facu* dado, int tam, float* por_apr, float* por_re )
{
    int i, total=0, total_apro=0, total_re=0;

    for ( i = 0; i < tam; ++i) {
        total += dado[i].mat;
        total_apro += dado[i].arpro;
        total_re += dado[i].rfreq;
    }

    *por_apr = ((float)(total_apro/total)) * 100;
    *por_re = ((float)(total_re/total)) * 100;
}

int main()
{
  int i, tam; /** declare a variavel do tamanho aqui. */
  float p_ap, p_re;

  printf("Quatos alunos ha: "); /* pergunte o tamanho do vetor, depois aloque-o */
  scanf(" %i", &tam);
  facu* d = (facu*)malloc(sizeof(facu) * tam);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < tam; ++i ) {
      printf("Digite a %i° disciplina: ", i+1);
      scanf(" %[^\n]s", d[i].disc );

      printf("digite quantos alunos foram matriculados na disciplina %s: ", d[i].disc);
      scanf(" %i", &d[i].mat );

      printf("digite quantos alunos foram aprovados na disciplina %s: ", d[i].disc);
      scanf(" %i", &d[i].arpro );

      printf("digite quantos alunos foram reprovados na disciplina %s: ", d[i].disc);
      scanf(" %i", &d[i].rfreq );
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < tam; ++i ) {
    printf("\nmatriculados %i\n", d[i].mat);
    printf("aprovados %i\n", d[i].arpro);
    }

    calculos(d, tam, &p_ap, &p_re);

    free(d);        

    return 0;

}
```

Para um melhor entendimento do que foi dito aqui estão alguns links que podem te ajudar:

Passagem por referência:

http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/Variaveis-apontadas-A-passagem-por-Referencia-em-C.html

Alocação dinâmica de memória:

http://www.cprogressivo.net/p/alocacao-dinamica-de-memoria-em-c.html

Tinha mais links, mas infelizmente não pude postar :(.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, estou meio que começando estruturas de dados na faculdade agora, e ainda estou com um pouco de dificuldades, existem outros problemas nesse exercício, mas o meu principal problema era esse, vc deu uma boa clareada, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Faltou `free(d);` antes do `return 0;`

Comment: sim, suashaushauhs, sempre esqueço, mas já foi editado e adicionado ali, muito obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Atenção que o `printf` da discplina não está certo, aqui: `printf("digite quantos alunos foram matriculados na disciplina %s: ", d[i]);`. Deveria ser `d[i].disc`. Esse erro existe nas varias impressões da disciplina

Comment: thx bro, nem tinha reparado isso.